# Why this function is running in an infinite loop?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn about recursion. I dont understand why the following piece of code runs in an infinite loop?

```
void myFunc(int n)
{
     if(n==0)
         return;
     else
     {
         printf("%d\n",n);
         myFunc(n--); //if I put n=n-1 before this line then it is running fine and will exit from the function .
         printf("%d\n",n); 
     }

}

int main()
{

    myFunc(4);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--` is a post-decrement operator as you are using it and only takes effect after `myFunc` is called with the value of `n`, so you will be calling `myFunc` with the same value over and over again.

Using it as a pre-decrement operator would fix your particular use case: `myFunc(--n)` would have a similar effect to putting `n=n-1` on the line before.

Answer (score 4):

n-- calls the postfix operation, which means the value of n gets passed into myFunc. After that, n's value is decremented by one.
Call myFunc(--n).

Answer (score 3):

Because the decrement is performed *after* the call. Not before.

If you do `myFunc(--n);` instead, it will work

Answer (score 3):

`n--` decrements `n` *after* `n` is passed to `myFunc()`, so `myFunc` is receiving the same `n` value every time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

n-- and --n are different.
You should look up C operators and sequence points for the explanation.
Basically, n-- means 'use n and decrement it at the next sequence point',
whereas --n means 'decrement n first and then use it'..

Answer (score 0):

N-- is a `postfix` operator. This means that it will increment the variable you are using it on after the value is used. As an example, in the expression `x * y--`, the compiler will return `x * y`, and then decrement y.